# Implementing Mysql Joins. How to get results in same row?

Tags: mysql, join

Link for Er Diagram:

[image]

I want to get data from the child tables.
Eg. I need location, equipments, language, service for all user_id. There are multiple values for location, equipment, language and service for a given user_id.

I tried the following code:

```
SELECT  user_detail.user_id , user_detail.name , user_equipment.equipment , user_location.location , user_service.service , user_language.language
          from user_detail
    INNER JOIN user_equipment on user_detail.user_id = user_equipment.user_id
    INNER JOIN  user_location on user_detail.user_id = user_location.user_id
    INNER JOIN user_service on user_detail.user_id = user_service.user_id
    INNER JOIN user_language on user_detail.user_id = user_language.user_id;
```

Now the problem is, if there are three location for a user_id I get three row, is there any way I get all location in same row?

Comment: The [mysql] tag has been added to this question - is this specfically for MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for this "GROUP_CONCAT", your query would look like this:

```
SELECT  user_detail.user_id ,
    user_detail.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(user_equipment.equipment SEPARATOR ',') as equipments,
    GROUP_CONCAT(user_location.location SEPARATOR  ',') as locations,
    GROUP_CONCAT(user_service.service SEPARATOR ',') as services,     
    GROUP_CONCAT(user_language.language SEPARATOR ',') as languages
FROM user_detail
    INNER JOIN user_equipment on user_detail.user_id = user_equipment.user_id
    INNER JOIN  user_location on user_detail.user_id = user_location.user_id
    INNER JOIN user_service on user_detail.user_id = user_service.user_id
    INNER JOIN user_language on user_detail.user_id = user_language.user_id;
GROUP BY user_detail.user_id
```

Comment: Now the results are fetched in same row but there are multiple duplicate entries for location , service and language. How do I resolve ? Here is the image - i.imgur.com/5vI6JK2 that shows the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce multiple lines to single lines for each user, by grouping by `user_id`. The `GROUP_CONCAT` function will enable you to see all values of `location` in the group - like so:

```
SELECT  user_detail.user_id , 
        user_detail.name ,  
        user_equipment.equipment ,  
        GROUP_CONCAT(user_location.location SEPARATOR ',') AS user_locations ,  
        user_service.service ,  
        user_language.language
from user_detail
    INNER JOIN user_equipment on user_detail.user_id = user_equipment.user_id
    INNER JOIN  user_location on user_detail.user_id = user_location.user_id
    INNER JOIN user_service on user_detail.user_id = user_service.user_id
    INNER JOIN user_language on user_detail.user_id = user_language.user_id
GROUP BY user_detail.user_id;
```

Note that this assumes there will always be one (and only one) equipment, service and language record for each user - if there can be more than one of each then you should use `GROUP_CONCAT` for their values (with a DISTINCT qualifier), while if the user might not have corresponding records the join to the relevant table should be changed to a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Now the results are fetched in same row but there are multiple duplicate entries for location . How do I resolve ? Here is the image - http://i.imgur.com/5vI6JK2 that shows the exact problem

Comment: @Rakesh: by including the DISTINCT qualifier in the `group_concat` function (as mentioned in the last paragraph of my answer).

Answer (score 0):

In situations where I can't use a GROUP_CONCAT call, I would do the select, then join them in some resulting code. I am unsure what application language you are using, but for something like php:

```
$select = $query(); //Returns the SELECT results
for($i = 0; $i < count($select); $i++){
  for($a = 0; $a < count($select); $a++){ //Double loop to check the entire list
    if($a !== !i){ //No point in selecting the same row and comparing it
        $location_count = 0;
        if($select[$a]['user_id'] === $select[$i]['user_id']){
          $locationref = 'location_'.$location_count++;
          $select[$i][$locationref] = $select[$a]['location'];
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Just my thoughts - untested but the general principle is there.

Comment: Using Php but I need the results in Json format. Thought I could fetch the results using php ,  encode to json and manipulate using angularjs. Got the solution anyway.

Comment: I would create this within a function: `function select_to_json () {}` and return the array with json_encode